# WORDPRESS Missing label in multicolor Kirki field

Tags: wordpress

In multicolor field, labels from colour pickers are missing. Code:

```
Kirki::add_field( $textdomain, [
    'type'        => 'multicolor',
    'settings'    => 'multicolor_setting',
    'label'       => esc_html__( 'Label', $textdomain ),
    'section'     => 'header__top_bar__general',
    'priority'    => 10,
    'choices'     => [
        'link'    => esc_html__( 'Color', $textdomain ),
        'hover'   => esc_html__( 'Hover', $textdomain ),
        'active'  => esc_html__( 'Active', $textdomain ),
    ],
    'default'     => [
        'link'    => '#0088cc',
        'hover'   => '#00aaff',
        'active'  => '#00ffff',
    ],
] );
```

result:

[image]

Console log:

```
wpColorPickerL10n.defaultLabel is deprecated since version 5.5.0! Use wp.i18n instead.
    
wpColorPickerL10n.pick is deprecated since version 5.5.0! Use wp.i18n instead.
    
wpColorPickerL10n.defaultString is deprecated since version 5.5.0! Use wp.i18n instead.
    
wpColorPickerL10n.defaultAriaLabel is deprecated since version 5.5.0! Use wp.i18n instead.
    
common.min.js?ver=5.7.1:2
```

WP 5.7.1, Kirki 3.1.6 from repository, theme_mod

any way to fix quick fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You might be a bit confused here. Why are you using `textdomain` both as the text domain for the translation AND as the first arguments for `add_field`? The first argument to the `add_field` method should be an existing config. As per the documentation:

```
Kirki::add_config( 'theme_config_id', array(
    'capability'    => 'edit_theme_options',
    'option_type'   => 'theme_mod',
) );
Kirki::add_panel( 'panel_id', array(
    'priority'    => 10,
    'title'       => esc_html__( 'My Panel', 'kirki' ),
    'description' => esc_html__( 'My panel description', 'kirki' ),
) );
Kirki::add_section( 'section_id', array(
    'title'          => esc_html__( 'My Section', 'kirki' ),
    'description'    => esc_html__( 'My section description.', 'kirki' ),
    'panel'          => 'panel_id',
    'priority'       => 160,
) );
Kirki::add_field( 'theme_config_id', [
    'type'        => 'multicolor',
    'settings'    => 'multicolor_setting',
    'label'       => esc_html__( 'Label', 'kirki' ),
    'section'     => 'section_id',
    'priority'    => 10,
    'choices'     => [
        'link'    => esc_html__( 'Color', 'kirki' ),
        'hover'   => esc_html__( 'Hover', 'kirki' ),
        'active'  => esc_html__( 'Active', 'kirki' ),
    ],
    'default'     => [
        'link'    => '#0088cc',
        'hover'   => '#00aaff',
        'active'  => '#00ffff',
    ],
] );
```

Here, `kirki` is an existing text domain. Your text domain seems not to exist. Try removing the text domains. Like this:

```
$kirki_config_id = '{YOUR KIRKI CONFIG ID}';
Kirki::add_field( $kirki_config_id, [
    'type'        => 'multicolor',
    'settings'    => 'multicolor_setting',
    'label'       => 'Label',
    'section'     => 'header__top_bar__general',
    'priority'    => 10,
    'choices'     => [
        'link'    => 'Color',
        'hover'   => 'Hover',
        'active'  => 'Active',
    ],
    'default'     => [
        'link'    => '#0088cc',
        'hover'   => '#00aaff',
        'active'  => '#00ffff',
    ],
] );
```

Does that do the trick?